# bxe0 and bxe1 to eth0 and eth1 respectively

Tags: boot, freebsd, ethernet, ifconfig

I have a freebsd which has the network interfaces as follows.

```
bxe0, bxe1, igd0 and igd1
```

I want to move them to names like eth0, eth1 and so on. I know that I can do it in the /etc/rc.conf

```
ifconfig_igb0_name=eth0
```

but during the boot time the network interfaces are still bxe0, bxe1 etc.
Is there any way I can change interface names I want before the kernel gets loaded ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are "kernel inventions"; they don't exist outside of the kernel.

So "can I give them different names before the kernel gets loaded" makes no sense – they don't exist before the kernel has initialized them.